# How to initialize enum from raw value

Tags: swift, enums

I'm having an enum that I'm trying to initialize to `case twentyFourHours` like this:

```
enum Duration: TimeInterval {
    case twentyFourHours
    
    var durationInSeconds: TimeInterval {
        switch self {
        case .twentyFourHours:
            return TimeInterval.init(86400)
        }
    }
    
    var durationInHours: Int {
        switch self {
        case .twentyFourHours:
            return 24
        }
    }
}
```

```
let interval = TimeInterval.init(86400)

guard let duration = Duration.init(rawValue: interval) else { throw ChallengeError.invalidDuration }
```

But I always get nil. Does anyone know why?

Seems like a basic thing I already should know!

Comment: What is *interval* in `Duration.init(rawValue: interval)`?

Comment: Ahh sorry I forgot to add it in the original post. I'll do it now

Comment: I don't think you understand how raw value works, you should read in [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID149) book about enum and raw values. Maybe you should try to explain what you want to accomplish here, maybe an enum is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
enum Duration: TimeInterval {
    case twentyFourHours = 86400

    var durationInSeconds: TimeInterval {
        return self.rawValue
    
    }

    var durationInHours: Int {
        return Int(self.rawValue / 3600)
    }
}
```

This equals to:

Duration(1234) // <- nil

Duration(86400) // <- .twentyFourHours

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `rawValue` if it's something other than 0, `TimeInterval` is a `typealias` for type `Double` and it defaults the first case rawValue to 0 if not specified.

```
enum Duration: TimeInterval {
    case twentyFourHours = 86400
    //...
}

let interval: TimeInterval = 86400
let duration = Duration(rawValue: interval) // and then you can initialize like this
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate answer to me.